# Maximum Size SDXC card on XP

Tags: windows, sdxc

I have a 64GB SD XC card for my Canon that my Windows XP computer will not recognize (but a Windows 7 machine will).

Assuming that the card reader recognizes it, what is the maximum size that I can get that my Windows XP machine will still read?

Answer (score 3):

Cards larger than 4GB, and SDXC, are formatted in the exFAT file system. Most newer PCs and Windows 7 can read this system, but your XP system does not. However, you should at least  try the Microsoft exFAT driver update to see if your system can support it.

I would also suggest that you only format (and erase) the card on the camera, not on your computer.

[Update for Windows XP (KB955704)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19364)

Comment: The referenced Windows XP update is no longer available, at least on the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no maximum size.** The issue you are having is that the SDXC card is format as exFAT. This happens to be the default when SDXC cards are shipped and also what cameras format the SDXC cards as.

There are two workaround:

- Install the [exFAT driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19364). (Link from @cmason's answer)
- Format the card as FAT32 on the computer. *While I have only tested a handful of cameras with it, all of them accepted 128 GB SDXC cards formatted as FAT32.*